# Open Chrome tab through Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to open a new tab in Chrome via Google Apps Script.

My trigger is From spreadsheet - On form submit

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: If the user has the spreadsheet open, then you could open a dialog box or sidebar, run client side code with `window.onload = function() {}`  and programmatically click an html link tag, making sure that the target is blank, then close the dialog box with `google.script.host.close();`

Comment: Got it, but... Should I do this using SpreadsheetApp, right? If so, my script can not call from this context. I think this is because the trigger (formSubmit)

Comment: If the form submit trigger is associated with the Google Form, then my suggestion won't work.  The Form Submit trigger is available to both a Google Form and a Google Sheet.  Your code would need to be bound to the Google Sheet, and the Form Submit trigger would need to run from the Sheet.  You need to be able to get the active spreadsheet, which you can only do from an Apps Script project bound to the Sheet, or an add-on.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Your trigger is executed on form submit. Someone could submit the form without having the Spreadsheet open. So where would the new Chrome window/tab open?

You can have a sidebar in a Google Sheet that can open a new window/tab but that requires human interaction. Meaning, the user would need to go to the Spreadsheet, click on something to load/open the sidebar, and then click a button that would open a new Chrome window/tab.